# League of Legends Voice Change while Not Changing Texts

Tags: file, overlay, mount

I've seen a lot of HOWTOs on the locale change of LoL, and it did work when I tried. But changing the locale parameter of the file "league_of_legends.live.product_settings.yaml" would influence the whole language. I suppose it would be more comfortable (personally speaking) if I could change the voices (mainly system report and champion voice) while not changing the texts, for example, gaming with English texts displayed, English champion voice heard and Japanese system report voice heard (my preference acc). So is there some approach to achieve this separate modification, like overlay mounting or something else? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.